# difference between calling angular.injector with and without ['ng']

Tags: angularjs

Documentation for `angular.injector` says that `'ng'` module must be added as a dependency here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector but documentation of `$injector` shows an example as shown below:

```
var $injector = angular.injector();
```

here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector 
What is the difference in the two approaches ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.bootstrap` adds `ng` module by default and calls `angular.injector` internally. `angular.injector` doesn't add `ng` module.

`angular.injector()` results in an injector where core Angular services are unavailable. When being used without `ng` module it is a generic DI container.